# Cannot Edit php parameters values (Upload Max File)

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I broke my head to find why the values of the PHP parameterization are not taken into my server.
I have prestashop on my server, default Upload Max File = 2M,
I changed the php.ini on /etc/php/7.4/fpm and on /etc/php/7.4/cli , but without any success.
I checked with php --ini to find out which file is currently being used, I also modified the parameters on the prestashop side but no result.
Any ideas ?

P.S: I did not forget to restart the services each time

Comment: How large is the file you're trying to upload? Have you also looked at the post_max_size setting?

Comment: @Don'tPanic a module that have 5 MB size, yes, i alsocheck the post_max_size.

Answer (score 0):

You might be editing wrong ini file. Print `phpinfo()` on server and check ***Loaded Configuration File*** in list; you will get path of ini file which is currently being loaded on your server.